# xcode45-dp4 notification center

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.5

After trying the developer previews Xcode is now displayed in Notification Center as "Xcode45-DP4". Even after installing the update and deleting Xcode45-DP4.app.

Is there a cache that needs to be cleared in order to correct it?